# Interval in which the roots of $3x^{2} - 12x + 11 + \frac{1}{5} (x^{3} -6x^{2} - 11x -6) = 0$ lie.

Tags: calculus

The equation $3x^{2} - 12x + 11 + \frac{1}{5} (x^{3} -6x^{2} - 11x -6) = 0$ has

1) exactly one root in the interval $(1,2)$

2) exactly three distinct roots in the interval $(1,2)$

Which option is correct?

I determined the value of this function at $1$ and $2$, which are $6$ and $-13$ respectively. Since, the function is continuous so it will have atleast one zero between $1$ and $2$.
But, this polynomial can also three roots between $1$ and $2$ if the roots are real. 
How can I check the validity of second option without finding out all the roots of the polynomial$?$

Comment: The polynomial goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ so if it takes the value $-13$ at $2$ it must have a root greater than $2$

Comment: Why don't you solve the equation $$\frac{1}{5} \left(16 x^3-6 x^2-71 x+49\right)=0$$ explicit?

Comment: Also, by Descartes' rule of signs, it has exactly one negative root.

Comment: @saulspatz by Descartes' rule of signs, it should have atmost one negative root. Why exactly?

Comment: The number of sign changes has the same parity as the number of roots, so if there is one sign change, there is exactly one root.

Comment: Please post the correct polynomial! Your evaluations at $1$ and $2$ are way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$3x^{2} - 12x + 11 + \frac{1}{5} (x^{3} -6x^{2} - 11x -6) = 0$$
is equivalent to
$$ x^3+9x^2-71x+49=0. $$
Let 
$$ f(x)=x^3+9x^2-71x+49. $$
Note that
$$ f'(x)=3x^2+18x-71<0, x\in[1,2]$$
and hence $f(x)$ is decreasing in $[1,2]$. Thus $f(x)$ reaches the maximum $f(1)=-12$ in $[1,2]$. So one has that $f(x)\le f(1)<0$ for $x\in[1,2]$; that is, $f(x)=0$ does not have roots in $[1,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you typed in, $3x^{2} - 12x + 11 + \frac{1}{5} (x^{3} -6x^{2} - 11x -6) = 0$ has no roots between $1$ and $2.$

The roots are roughly -14.231, 0.7722, and 4.4588

Answer (score 1):

This is a cubic equation, so it has at most three roots in total. And the coefficient of its leading term, $\frac15 x^3$, is positive, so it tends to $-\infty$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ and to $+\infty$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

This is all you need!

The value at $1$ is positive, so it has a root in $(-\infty,1)$. And the value at $2$ is negative, so it has a root in $(2,+\infty)$. That accounts for two of the roots, so it can have at most one root in $(1,2)$.

**Edited to add:** Hmm, it seems your evaluation at $1$ is off. So this answer is invalid.